# update GUI when model array is reordered in Angular

Tags: angular

I am having an array of objects.

```
sharedObjects = [{id:1, name:"Tim"},{id:2, name:"Duncan"},{id:3, name:"James"}];
```

I than reorder sharedObjects to form a slight different array composed of the exact same objects:

```
sharedObjects = [{id:2, name:"Duncan"},{id:3, name:"James"},{id:1, name:"Tim"}];
```

I am doing that by removing the first element, store it in array, and concating array to the desired index.

For some reason GUI does not update to reflect this change. I tried using `changeDetectorRef.detectChanges()`, but it triggers nothing.

GUI updates if I add a new element to array, delete an element, and call detectChanges(), but simply reordering the same array does nothing.

How should I fix that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [official angular documentation](https://angular.io/api/common/NgForOf), the change propagation in `ngFor` takes place as follows -

1. When an item is added, a new instance of the template is added to the DOM.
   When
2. an item is removed, its template instance is removed from the DOM.
   When
3. items are reordered, their respective templates are reordered in the DOM.

As per the third point, your template should update itself according to the re-ordering.

Sharing your code might help in pointing out the actual problem.

Comment: hm. thanks, I will try to make a reasonably small example

Comment: It was my bad. in `ngOnInit` i had `dataForNgFor = someobject.getFunction().sharedObjects`.  I restructured the binding to something like this: `precursorObject = someobject.getFunction(); dataForNgFor = precursorObject.sharedObjects`and update was instant.